# Graphviz as a library: Valgrind showing memory leaks

Tags: c, valgrind, graphviz

I am using a slightly modified version of the first sample usage of the c graphviz library from here: https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/libguide.pdf . I modified the code by hard coding the graph to generate from the example given here https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/about-Graphviz/blob/master/examples/multiple-edges.dot.

```c
#include <graphviz/gvc.h>

int main()
{
  GVC_t *gvc;
  Agraph_t *g;
  gvc = gvContext();
  g = agmemread("digraph D {\n"
                "\n"
                "  A -> {B, C, D} -> {F}\n"
                "\n"
                "}");
  gvLayout(gvc, g, "dot");
  gvRender(gvc, g, "plain", stdout);
  gvFreeLayout(gvc, g);
  agclose(g);
  return (gvFreeContext(gvc));
}
```

When running Valgrind `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes --show-leak-kinds=all --log-file=valgrind-out.txt --track-origins=yes ./main` on that I see

```
==43900== LEAK SUMMARY:
==43900==    definitely lost: 166,548 bytes in 634 blocks
==43900==    indirectly lost: 220,201 bytes in 8,843 blocks
==43900==      possibly lost: 1,522 bytes in 21 blocks
==43900==    still reachable: 554,001 bytes in 7,973 blocks
==43900==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==43900==                         length64           : 80 bytes in 2 blocks
==43900==                         newarray           : 1,568 bytes in 18 blocks
==43900==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==43900== 
==43900== ERROR SUMMARY: 25 errors from 25 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

(or https://justpaste.it/8x11f for the full log)

In fact even if I don't bother with the layout and I write code like so

```c
#include <graphviz/gvc.h>

int main() {
  Agraph_t *g = agmemread("digraph D {\n"
                          "\n"
                          "  A -> {B, C, D} -> {F}\n"
                          "\n"
                          "}");
  agwrite(g, stdout);
  agclose(g);
  return 0;
}
```

Valgrind still outputs

```
==44688== LEAK SUMMARY:
==44688==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==44688==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==44688==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==44688==    still reachable: 24,762 bytes in 6 blocks
==44688==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

(or https://justpaste.it/97hjj for the full log)

What needs to be done to remove all leaks?

Comment: So you know valgrind tells you that you should rerun your program with some option. So please post the output of full leaks output from valgrind.

Comment: Re-run valgrind with `--leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes` and report back.

Comment: @KamilCuk I edited the question, added the command I sent and a link to the full output (it is too large to add to the question directly)

Comment: @Marco Bonelli edited